# Concatinate preceding "and" for any key which is second or more

Tags: ruby

I have a simple iteration:

```
hash = {key1: true, key2: false, key3: true, key4: true}

hash.each do |k,v| do
  puts k if v == true
end
```

and my output would be

```
key1
key3
key4
```

But I want to add a preceding `"and"` for each key if there is more than one:

```
key1 and key3 and key4
```

Any help?

Comment: You don't want the new lines?

Comment: If you "add a preceding `"and"` [and a space] for each key", then you would get: `"and key1 and key3 and key4"`.

Comment: _Sidenote_: I gave an answer to this question in your previous question.

Comment: @mudasobwa It was similar, but was actually different question. But the OP should decide an answer to accept in the previous question before going on to this one.

Comment: @mudasobwa I commented on that

Comment: @sawa preceding and on any which is not the first

Comment: @supersize You have to write all those things in the question from the beginning, not in a comment one after another when someone asks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select` method and `join` method to add "and" to each key.

```
hash = {key1: true, key2: false, key3: true, key4: true}
hash.select{|k, v| v}.keys.join(" and ")
# => "key1 and key3 and key4"
```

Comment: nice, but I want to have it for "each"

Comment: @supersize You whant to use `each` method insted of `select`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to `puts` it in the `each` loop, here you go:

```
hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), acc|
  if v == true
    print "#{' and ' unless acc.empty?}#{k}"
    acc << true
  end
end
puts # to carriage return
```

or, with pure `each` (PHP style):

```
subsequent = false
hash.each do |k, v|
  if v == true
    print "#{' and ' if subsequent}#{k}"
    subsequent = true
  end
end
puts # to carriage return
```

Please note I utilize `print` not `puts` since `puts` appends `$/` to the output automatically.

Comment: that looks horrible, okay I better sort out the select way!

Comment: @supersize You had asked, I have answered. It is your problem it looks horrible.

Comment: sure! I thought there would be an easier "magic" way.

Comment: @supersize: The *magic* is to use `select`...